# Proof/disprove contunuity of a map

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I need help with proving / disproving something:

> Look at the map
>
> $$\Phi: (C([0,1], \mathbb R), ||\cdot||_{\infty}) \to (\mathbb R, |\cdot|); \,\,\,\,\,\,\Phi(u) := \int_0^1 u²(t) dt$$
>
> a) Is it continuous?
>   b) Is uniformly continuus?
>   c) Can one find a non-empty subset of $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ in which $\Phi$ is Lipschitz-continuous?

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

For (a) & (c):

$\Phi(u)-\Phi(u') = \int (u-u')(u+u')$ and so 
$\|\Phi(u)-\Phi(u')\| \le  \|u-u' \| \| u+u' \|$.

If you just consider constant functions  you should be able to answer (b).